# Recovering InnoDB database from backed up “data” folder in XAMP in Windows 10

Tags: innodb, mariadb, recovery, windows-10

I copied the **data** directory from mysql folder and uninstalled the XAMPP as the MariaDB was not starting. I installed XAMPP same version and backed up the **data** folder into mysql data directory. At first only copied the required database folder named **production** inside the mysql data directory. PhpMyAdmin showed the tables correctly though no record/row was there and it showed "Table doesn't exist in engine". Then I copied all the contents from the DATA folder to the mysql data folder and now it does not start. **Now the problem is MariaDB is not starting**. I tried setting the
**innodb_force_recovery** but it failed to start the mysql.

The error log is given below:

```
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 3 in a file operation.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: '.\jobs\applied.ibd' OS error: 203
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 203 in a file operation.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for ``jobs`.`applied``. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace for `jobs`.`applied` because it could not be opened.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 3 in a file operation.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: '.\jobs\data.ibd' OS error: 203
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 203 in a file operation.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for ``jobs`.`data``. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace for `jobs`.`data` because it could not be opened.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 3 in a file operation.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: '.\jobs\data_employer.ibd' OS error: 203
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 203 in a file operation.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for ``jobs`.`data_employer``. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace for `jobs`.`data_employer` because it could not be opened.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 3 in a file operation.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: '.\jobs\education.ibd' OS error: 203
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 203 in a file operation.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for ``jobs`.`education``. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace for `jobs`.`education` because it could not be opened.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 3 in a file operation.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: '.\jobs\education_list.ibd' OS error: 203
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 203 in a file operation.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for ``jobs`.`education_list``. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace for `jobs`.`education_list` because it could not be opened.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 3 in a file operation.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: '.\jobs\industry.ibd' OS error: 203
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 203 in a file operation.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for ``jobs`.`industry``. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace for `jobs`.`industry` because it could not be opened.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 3 in a file operation.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: '.\jobs\jobs.ibd' OS error: 203
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 203 in a file operation.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for ``jobs`.`jobs``. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace for `jobs`.`jobs` because it could not be opened.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 3 in a file operation.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: '.\jobs\login.ibd' OS error: 203
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 203 in a file operation.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for ``jobs`.`login``. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace for `jobs`.`login` because it could not be opened.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 3 in a file operation.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: '.\jobs\login_admini.ibd' OS error: 203
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 203 in a file operation.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for ``jobs`.`login_admini``. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace for `jobs`.`login_admini` because it could not be opened.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 3 in a file operation.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: '.\jobs\login_employer.ibd' OS error: 203
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 203 in a file operation.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for ``jobs`.`login_employer``. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace for `jobs`.`login_employer` because it could not be opened.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 3 in a file operation.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: '.\jobs\resume.ibd' OS error: 203
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 203 in a file operation.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for ``jobs`.`resume``. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace for `jobs`.`resume` because it could not be opened.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 3 in a file operation.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: '.\jobs\selected.ibd' OS error: 203
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 203 in a file operation.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for ``jobs`.`selected``. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace for `jobs`.`selected` because it could not be opened.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 3 in a file operation.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: '.\projects\entries.ibd' OS error: 203
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 203 in a file operation.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for ``projects`.`entries``. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace for `projects`.`entries` because it could not be opened.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 3 in a file operation.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: '.\projects\geoname.ibd' OS error: 203
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 203 in a file operation.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for ``projects`.`geoname``. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace for `projects`.`geoname` because it could not be opened.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 3 in a file operation.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: '.\projects\geonamebackup.ibd' OS error: 203
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 203 in a file operation.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for ``projects`.`geonamebackup``. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace for `projects`.`geonamebackup` because it could not be opened.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 3 in a file operation.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: '.\projects\pincodes.ibd' OS error: 203
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 203 in a file operation.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for ``projects`.`pincodes``. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace for `projects`.`pincodes` because it could not be opened.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 3 in a file operation.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: '.\projects\specifier.ibd' OS error: 203
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 203 in a file operation.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for ``projects`.`specifier``. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace for `projects`.`specifier` because it could not be opened.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 3 in a file operation.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: '.\projects\users.ibd' OS error: 203
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 203 in a file operation.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for ``projects`.`users``. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace for `projects`.`users` because it could not be opened.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'D:\Program Files\XAMP\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'D:\Program Files\XAMP\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.19 started; log sequence number 1515509790; transaction id 611499
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from D:\Program Files\XAMP\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2021-06-11  0:08:23 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was able to get back the data.
Step 1: Move all the file from mysql/**data** directory to data_old directory except mysql and performance_schema directory.
Step 2: Copy back the **ibdata1** file from backed up directory also copy back the folder with the name of the database you want to restore.
Step 3: now start mysql, you will be able to see the database. use **mysqldump** to export to a sql file.
Step 4: Uninstall mysql / xampp. Re-install xampp.
Step 5: create a database with the name of the backed up database. and use mysqldump to restore the data.

Also remember phpMyAdmin may not work after deleting it's database, so you may need to switch to console.